# Name of linux shell command mapped to a given keyboard shortcut?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, return, keyboard-shortcuts

Not sure how to query for what I am looking for in a search engine:

I want to determine the names of Linux shell commands that are mapped to default keyboard shortcuts (return, backspace, ctrl+c, etc.).

For instance, I want to know the explicit name of the command that is executed when I press "return". I don't just want a link to "basic shell commands", I want to know the mappings in the command-line instance I am currently on.

Comment: you mean the actual key mapping? return => char code 0x13 kinda thing?

Comment: Yes (I think) sorry if this sounds confusing (I lack the terminology of what I am looking for), for instance it would be nice to type a command in my current linux terminal and have it print a list of command names next to the keyboard shortcuts, OR perhaps there is a file somewhere I can look into.

Comment: look into `dumpkeys`.

Comment: no such thing. key presses are events processed by the kernel and a bunch of layers including `stty` (which sort of filter what is happening). The meaning of those key-presses is the interpreted by a running program. From the cmd-line, that program is your shell (bash, ksh, zsh, etc). If you launched a program, like mail, the key presses are processed by the program mail. Some of the super `c` programmers will be able to explain it in further detail or correct my admittedly quickly drawn picture. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm.. well for instance in the script editor: sublime text 2 (ST2) and vim you can program in your own custom keyboard shortcuts and these key-bindings are stored in a file. There is no such thing such as this ?

Comment: You wrote 'I want to know the explicit name of the command that is executed when I press "return".'  Custom keyboard shortcuts inside the `sublime` editor will not work in the `vim` or `emacs` editors, and so the keypresses are processed uniquely by each editor program. There is not a special program just to process the "return" key. Each program has the option of doing what ever it wants when the "return" key is pressed (although that would violate decades-old assumptions about how keyboards work). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [pretty-print all active `readline` key bindings](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/f7ea45dc185e3f3d9ab30c5054c309abce50038a/.bash_history#L43):

```
bind -P | grep --fixed-strings ' can be found on ' | perl -pe 's/((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\\C/\1Ctrl/g;s/((?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\\e/\1Esc,/g'
```

That said, some bindings like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> are not mapped to "shell commands" but rather to *internal functions* of the current shell. To figure out what a shell does when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> you'd have to refer to the actual source code of the program which captures the shortcut, which could include anything from the shell to any other program in the foreground of the stack running in the shell.